# How do I order IBM Cloud (Softlayer) storage by the hour

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to order IBM Cloud (Softlayer) Performance Storage by the hour. I'm able to order storage monthly but I'm not able to determine the ids to use for hourly billing. Here is my example order json for obtaining the storage monthly as a reference.

```
{
"parameters": [{
            "location": "1004995",
    "packageId": 222,
    "osFormatType": {
        "id": 12,
        "keyName": "LINUX"
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Iscsi",
    "prices": [{
        "item": {
            "description": "Block Storage (Performance)"
        },
        "id": "40678"
    }, {
        "item": {
            "description": ": 250 GB Storage Space"
        },
        "id": "40728"
    }, {
        "item": {
            "description": ": 2500 IOPS"
        },
        "id": "41738"
    }]
}]
}
```

How do I find out the order IDs I would need to use in order to get hourly billing instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another package, the package 759 you need to use, I guess you know how to get the prices but just in case you need to use the [Softlayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_product_package/getitemprices) method

```
{
        "parameters": [{
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
            "location": 449494,
            "quantity": 1,
            "packageId": 759,
            "volumeSize": 10,
            "prices": [{
                    "id": 189433  --> Storage as a Service
                },
                {
                    "id": 193373  --> 2 IOPS per GB
                }, {
                    "id": 189443  --> Block Storage
                }, {
                    "id": 193613  --> 10 GB Storage Space
                }, {
                    "id": 193433  --> Storage space for 2 IOPS per GB
                }
            ],
            "osFormatType": {
                "id": 12,
                "keyName": "LINUX"
            }
        }]
    }
```